# Is there a way to give read permissions for a non public firestore document without requiring the user to have an account?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

For example is there a way to issue a JWT or something from my server to let them have access to a particular document, without requiring them to go through Firebase authentication? I'd like them to be able to read directly from Firestore but not require an account to do so, while not opening up the document to everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore does not offer any forms of authorization that aren't related to Firebase Authentication.  Or, in other words, Firebase Auth accounts are the only supported mechanism to distinguish which individuals can read and write documents.

It sounds like you should probably create your own backend endpoint that accepts a token, check it for validity, and determines if the bearer of that token should be able to read the contents of the requested document.  The backend would have to perform the query directly, and it will be able to bypass security rules.

Comment: Ah ok, that is unfortunate. I will have to think about the best way to do this in a scalable way. I was looking forward to letting Google deal with that part of it.

Comment: There's nothing inherently unscalable about introducing a backend, especially if it's Cloud Functions or Cloud Run, which both scale automatically. In fact, it's quite common.

Comment: yeah it is just more annoying to spin up a service specifically for this and to pay for the extra bandwidth

Comment: Ok I didn't realize that anonymous accounts are a thing, I am going to use those